# Does anyone know how to calculate the Coppock Curve in python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to calculate the Coppock Curve for a strategy i'm making in python. 
I've written it like this(ROC1 is the 11 length and the ROC2 is the 14 length):

```
final  = wma_onehr*(rocOne_onehr+rocTwo_onehr)
```

I know my values are correct but this is the only calculation for it and it does not match with tradingview at all. For instance when I run it I get

```
ROC1: -1.094 
ROC2: -0.961
WMA: 7215.866
```

And my answer is `-15037.864744`
While Tradingview is at `-0.9`

These values are know where near close and i'm just wondering why I have not found a way to get a value like that of any kind. (I'm using taapio api if anyones wondering)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at below function. Note that `data_array` that is passed to function is a one dimensional numpy array that contains `close` prices of financial asset.

```
import numpy as np


def coppock_curve(data_array, sht_roc_length=11, long_roc_length=14, curve_length=10):  # Coppock Curve
    """
    :param sht_roc_length: Short Rate of Change length
    :param long_roc_length: Long Rate of Change length
    :param curve_length: Coppock Curve Line length
    :return: Coppock oscillator values 
    """
    data_array = data_array[-(curve_length + max(sht_roc_length, long_roc_length, curve_length) + 1):]
    # Calculation of short rate of change
    roc11 = (data_array[-(curve_length + 1):] - data_array[-(curve_length + sht_roc_length + 1):-sht_roc_length]) /\
        data_array[-(curve_length + sht_roc_length + 1):-sht_roc_length] * 100
    roc14 = (data_array[-(curve_length + 1):] - data_array[:-long_roc_length]) / data_array[:-long_roc_length] * 100
    sum_values = roc11 + roc14  # calculation of long rate of change
    curve = np.convolve(sum_values, np.arange(1, curve_length + 1, dtype=int)[::-1], 'valid') / \
        np.arange(1, curve_length + 1).sum()  # calculation of coppock curve line
```

Comment: Do you know where I can get these values

Comment: @Tony at the time I used quandl to get this data. For now, I don't it that source is still active or not. You should make your own search for data source.

Comment: Sorry this answer just wasn't very clear, I pull my data from an API already. I just can't understand why my calculations wont work.